# How to generate HTML table with nested loop?

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I have a table that should look like the following:

http://hell-rider.de/Fotos/img/beispiel-1.JPG

I have the following PHP script:

```
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row){
    if($row{'refTypeID'} == 42){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<th>";
        echo $row{'date'};
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
        echo '' . $row{'ownerName1'} .'';
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
        foreach ($allgemeinxml->result->rowset->row as $type){
            echo '' . $type{'typeName'} .'';
        }
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
        echo '<p class="minus">' . $row{'amount'} .' ISK</p>';
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
        echo '<p class="kontostand">' . $row{'balance'} . ' ISK</p>';
        echo "</th>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

The actual output of my script is the following, however:

http://hell-rider.de/Fotos/img/beispiel2.JPG

How do I have to change my script to populate the third column correctly (and not with *MetallurgyTradeLaboratory OperationLaboratory OperationLaboratory OperationResearchCybernetics*)?

Comment: So you want it to say `Cybernetics` instead of `MetallurgyTradeLaboratory OperationLaboratory OperationLaboratory OperationResearchCybernetics`?

Comment: yes every cell down new text

Comment: picture one shows the same text in every cell though, is that not what you want? Do you want each cell to have something different under the gegenstand heading?

Comment: @Geuthur sorry to say that your question was barely intelligible for me. I have edited it to the best of my understanding in order to make your actual question clearer and to encourage better answers. Please check whether my edit preserved your original meaning and don't be afraid to yell otherwise.

Comment: @helmbert i make a picture [link]http://hell-rider.de/Fotos/img/beispiel3.png

Comment: The images are no longer available. Please update your question with valid links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<th>` tags are for header cells, you should be using `<td>` data cells.

```
$types = array();

foreach ($allgemeinxml->result->rowset->row as $type){
    $types[] = $type{'typeName'};
}

$type_index = 0;

foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row){
    if($row{'refTypeID'} == 42){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row{'date'};
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '' . $row{'ownerName1'} .'';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $types[$type_index];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<p class="minus">' . $row{'amount'} .' ISK</p>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<p class="kontostand">' . $row{'balance'} . ' ISK</p>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $type_index++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

I don't know exactly what the use of `if($row{'refTypeID'} == 42){` is, so you either want `$type_index++;` in the place I've put it above, or just above the closing brace `}`. For this to work well, `$allgemeinxml->result->rowset->row` and `$xml->result->rowset->row` need the same number of elements.

Comment: sry my bad thats not array when i change { then doesnt work
When i Use the script then i got this 
Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /var/customers/webs/ni7378_5/Eve/test.php on line 150

Its XML Format i think

Comment: @Geuthur Oh, my mistake sorry. If you `var_dump($allgemeinxml->result->rowset->row)` somewhere, what output does it give you? Knowing the structure of the object is necessary.

Comment: `object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(14) { ["transactionDateTime"]=> string(19) "2015-04-22 10:02:17" ["transactionID"]=> string(10) "3898981967" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["typeName"]=> string(10) "Metallurgy" ["typeID"]=> string(4) "3409" ["price"]=> string(9) "358749.99" ["clientID"]=> string(8) "95203460" ["clientName"]=> string(23) "Jackmerius Tackheritrix" ["stationID"]=> string(8) "60003760" ["stationName"]=> string(46) "Jita IV - Moon 4 - Caldari Navy Assembly Plant" ["transactionType"]=> string(3) "buy" ["transactionFor"]=> string(8) "personal" ["... and more

Comment: it works thanks very much :)
I learned a new string for my php language^^